# jQuery form validation on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple page with a form and a button outside the form. I am trying to validate the form on the button click.
I have added the rules for validation of the form on the document.onready function. However the form is not getting validated.

HTML:-

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="lib/jquery1.5.2.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/jquery.validate.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/myjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
     Field 1: <input id="field1" type="text" class="required">
</form>

<div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#form1").validate({
   rules: {
     field1: "required"
   },
   messages: {
     field1: "Please specify your name"

   }
})

$('#btn').click(function() {
 $("#form1").validate();  // This is not working and is not validating the form
});

});
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error?

Comment: What plugin are you using for validation?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.5.2.js and jquery.validate.js

Comment: To the commenters: `.validate()` inside the `click` handler is not working because it's only re-initializing the plugin.  Use `.valid()` to force validation.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Within your `click` handler, the mistake is the `.validate()` method; it only initializes the plugin, it does not validate the `form`.

To eliminate the need to have a `submit` button within the `form`, use `.valid()` to trigger a validation check...

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    $("#form1").valid();
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aog1tgz1/)

`.validate()` - to initialize the plugin (with options) *once* on DOM ready.

`.valid()` - to check validation state (boolean value) or to trigger a validation test on the `form` at any time.

Otherwise, if you had a `type="submit"` button within the `form` container, you would not need a special `click` handler and the `.valid()` method, as the plugin would capture that automatically.

[**Demo without `click` handler**](http://jsfiddle.net/6he8a15n/)

---

**EDIT**:

You also have two issues within your HTML...

```
<input id="field1" type="text" class="required">
```

- You don't need `class="required"` when declaring rules within `.validate()`.  It's redundant and  superfluous.
- The `name` attribute is missing.  Rules are declared within `.validate()` by their `name`.  The plugin depends upon unique `name` attributes to keep track of the inputs.

Should be...

```
<input name="field1" id="field1" type="text" />
```

Comment: I edited your answer, to make it work for a different kind of form structure. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28723145/2615737

Comment: I think it's ironic that you say both superfluous and redundant.

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks a lot @Sparky

Comment: Instead of `class="required"`I use the attribute `<input name="field1" id="field1" type="text" required />` that will automatically enters the validation script

Comment: @ArtFranco, this plugin allows you to declare rules by class or by HTML5 attributes.  Regardless, you must have missed the point of the answer... that no inline attributes are needed whenever the rules are defined within `.validate()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            field1: "Please specify your name"
        }
    })
});

<form id="form1" name="form1">
     Field 1: <input id="field1" type="text" class="required">
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>
```

You are also you using type="button". And I'm not sure why you ought to separate the submit button, place it within the form. It's more proper to do it that way. This should work.

Comment: True. But could I at least get back my vote?haha Just a trivial mistake, and an oversight on my part. ;p ...Never did I say that it's wrong, I just said that it's cleaner that way. Generally speaking.

Comment: Why always find fault? Just tried to help by giving a working alternative, as quickly as I can so he can make use of it if it turns out that it's what he's looking for. It's not like I'm trolling. Exchanging comments is a long process, you know. Better look at the bright side, man.

Comment: SO is about quality answers to specific questions... nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve other way using **button** tag

According new html5 attribute you also can add a form attribute like

```
<form id="formId">
    <input type="text" name="fname">
</form>

<button id="myButton" form='#formId'>My Awesome Button</button>
```

So the button will be attached to the form.

This should work with the validate() plugin of jQuery like :

```
var validator = $( "#formId" ).validate();
validator.element( "#myButton" );
```

It's working too with **input** tag

### Source :

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Button