# jQuery form validation using button and ajax submission(without page refresh)

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form in which i use ajax call to submit it to the servlet. The problem is that i am not able to validate it as i am submitting the form using a button. I came across this link but I am not able to find a solution to my problem
[jQuery form validation on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671710/jquery-form-validation-on-button-click)

my html code is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    <%@include file="/formsub/formstyle.css" %>
    </style>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({

          altFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'       
    });



    var form = $('#form1');
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        alert("in click");
        $(form).validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {

                $.get(form.attr('action'),$(form).serialize(),function(data,status){

         $('#json').val(" Firstname is "+data.firstname 
               +"\n Lastname is "+data.lastname

               +"\n You are a " +data.sex
               +"\n Your interests are " +data.interest
               +"\n Date of birth " +data.datepicker
               +"\n Your ipaddress " +data.userIpAddress    )
                });
            }   
        });
       });
     });
</script>

</head>
```

the click function is getting called but the validation is not happening. I am using button because i don want the page to refresh.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [that very same link you included in your submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671710/jquery-form-validation-on-button-click):

> Within your `click` handler, the mistake is that `.validate()` only re-initializes the plugin, it does not validate the `form`.

Therefore, this call:

```
$(form).validate( ...
```

should be placed *outside* the `click` handler, and the `$.get` call you do within it must be relocated within a `.submit(function () {... })`, which is called after validation occurs.

This is as much as I can tell you without a fiddle.