# Validating a Google Apps Form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, google-apps-script

I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013693/google-forms-file-upload-complete-example/22980821#22980821) to feed inputs and image submissions from a form into a Google Sheet and Folder on Google Drive.

I need to validate a few of the fields - just requiring them to be filled out. Unfortunately, the solution I'm using uses a type="button" to submit the form instead of type="submit" and I'm not quite adept enough at Javascript to change that.

However, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671710/jquery-form-validation-on-button-click) for validating a form with a type="button" submit - but it's not working. With that implemented my form just does nothing - doesn't validate, doesn't submit.

This specifically is the bit of Javascript I'm struggling to get working:

```
     //Validate Form
function() {
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please specify your name"

    }
})

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#myForm").valid();
});
};
```

It works fine in normal HTML in my browser - but doesn't work in Google Apps, so I'm assuming there's some comma or something in the wrong place since it seems Google has different JS requirements?

The rest of my code and a link to the sheet/form/script are below:

**Form.html**

```
<body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    // Javascript function called by "submit" button handler,
    // to show results.
    function updateOutput(resultHtml) {
      toggle_visibility('inProgress');
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = resultHtml;
    };


    // From blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
      else
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }'

   //Toggle Secondary Categories
   $(function() {
      $(".box").not("." + this.id).hide(); $("." + this.id).show();
    });

    //Calculate Split
    function check(split)
    {
    var split=document.forms[0].split.value
    var amount=document.forms[0].amount.value
    var tip = (amount*split) 
    document.forms[0].manufacturer.value=tip 
    var tip2 = (amount-tip)
    document.forms[0].pace.value=tip2
    };

   //Validate Form
    function() {
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please specify your name"

        }
    })

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#myForm").valid();
    });
    };
  </script>

  <div id="formDiv" class="form">
    <!-- Form div will be hidden after form submission -->
<form id="myForm">    
<div class="row">

<h1>Co-op Submission Form</h1>
<h2>Please fill out the form completely, including uploading any documentation associated with your co-op claim.</h2>
</div>
<h3>Your Information</h3>
      <h4>Name:</h4> <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control mustHave"/><br/>
      <h4>Email:</h4> <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control mustHave"/><br/>
<h3>Co-Op Information</h3>
       <h4>Brand:</h4>
      <select name="brand" class="form-control">
        <option>Select Option</option>
        <option>Bluebird</option>
        <option>Brown</option>
        <option>Ferris</option>
        <option>Giant Vac</option>
        <option>Honda</option>
        <option>Hurricane</option>
        <option>Jonsered</option>
        <option>Little Wonder</option>
        <option>RedMax</option>
        <option>SCAG</option>
        <option>Snapper Pro</option>
        <option>Sno-Way</option>
        <option>SnowEx</option>
        <option>Wright</option>
        <option>Ybravo</option>
      </select><br/>
      <h4>Invoice Date:</h4> <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control"/><br/>
     <h4> Total Co-Op Amount</h4> <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control"/><br />
      <h4>Co-Op Split:</h4>
      <input type="radio" name="split" onclick="check(this.value)" value="1">100%<br> 
      <input type="radio" name="split" onclick="check(this.value)" value=".5">50/50<br> 
      <input type="radio" name="split" onclick="check(this.value)" value=".75">75/25<br />
      <input type="radio" name="split" onclick="check(this.value)" value=".25">25/75 (Dealer Pays 50%)<br />

<h4>Manufacturer Amount:</h4> <input type="text" name="manufacturer" style="border:none;font-weight:bold;"><br />
<h4>Pace Amount:</h4> <input type="text" name="pace" style="border:none;font-weight:bold;" >
<h4>Description:</h4> <input name="reason" type="text" cols="20" rows="5" class="form-control mustHave"/><br />

      <h4>Co-Op Category:</h4>
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="dealer" value="Dealer Advertising">Dealer Advertising<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="online" value="Digital/Online Marketing">Digital/Online Advertising<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="meetings" value="Meetings and Schools">Meetings and Schools<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="advertising" value="PACE Advertising">PACE Advertising<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="pricing" value="Program Pricing Promotions">Program Pricing Promotions<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="correspondence" value="PACE-to-Dealer Correspondence">PACE-to-Dealer Correspondence<br />
      Other: <input type="text" id="other" name="category" class="form-control"/><br />
<!--Dealer Advertising-->
      <div class="dealer box" style="display:none;">
      <h4>Dealer Advertising:</h4>
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Billboards">Billboards<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Logo Merch">Logo Merch (hats, shirts, pens, etc.)<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Magazine/Newspaper">Magazine/Newspaper<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Open House/Trade Show">Open House & Dealer Trade Show<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="POP">POP (lit, posters,displays, etc)<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Radio">Radio<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="PACE Trade Show">PACE Trade Show<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="TV">TV<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Direct Mail">Direct Mail (post cards, flyers)<br />
 <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Sponsorships">Sponsorships<br />
      </div>

<!--Digital/Online Advertising-->
      <div class="online box" style="display: none;">
       <h4>Digital/Online Marketing:</h4>
         <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="CMS/Advertising">CMS/Dealer Website Advertising<br />
         <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="TRM Digital Marketing">TRM Digital Marketing (google, facebook, retargeting, demo site, youtube)
      </div>

<!--Meetings and Schools-->
      <div class="meetings box" style="display: none;">
      </div>

<!--PACE Advertising-->
      <div class="advertising box" style="display: none;">
         <h4>PACE Advertising:</h4>
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Billboards">Billboards<br />
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Logo Merch">Logo Merch (hats, shirts, pens, etc.)<br />
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="POP">POP (lit, posters,displays, etc)<br />
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="PACE Trade Show">PACE Trade Show<br />
    </div>

<!--Program Pricing Promotions-->
      <div class="pricing box" style="display: none;">
        <h4>Program Pricing Promotions:</h4>
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Promo Prices, Discounts, Rebates - Unassigned">Promo Prices, Discounts, Rebates - Unassigned<br />   
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Promo Pricing">Promo Pricing<br />          
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Demo">Demo<br />  
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Fleet">Fleet<br />   
          <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Spiffs and Rebates">Spiffs and Rebates<br />  
      </div>

<!--PACE-to-Dealer Correspondence-->
      <div class="correspondence box" style="display: none;">
        <h4>PACE-to-Dealer Correspondence:</h4>
            <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Pacesetter Catalog">Pacesetter Catalog<br /> 
            <input type="radio" name="subcategory" value="Dealer Programs (updates, reprints)">Dealer Programs (updates, reprints)<br /> 
      </div>



      <h4>Message:</h4> <textarea name="message" class="form-control"></textarea><br/>
      <h4> Supporting Documentation:</h4>
      <input name="myFile1" type="file"/>
      <a onclick="document.getElementById('div1').style.display='';return false;" href="">Submit More</a><br />


      <div id="div1" style="display:none;margin: 15px 0;">
         <input name="myFile2" type="file"/>
         <a onclick="document.getElementById('div2').style.display='';return false;" href="">Submit More</a><br />
      </div>

      <div id="div2" style="display:none;margin: 15px 0;">
         <input name="myFile3" type="file"/>
         <a onclick="document.getElementById('div3').style.display='';return false;" href="">Submit More</a><br />
      </div>

      <div id="div3" style="display:none;margin: 15px 0;">
         <input name="myFile4" type="file"/>
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('div4').style.display='';return false;" href="">Submit More</a><br />
      </div>

      <div id="div4" style="display:none;margin: 15px 0;">
      <input name="myFile5" type="file"/><br /></div>
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Validate" id="btn" class="btn" onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv'); toggle_visibility('inProgress');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>

      <div id="inProgress" style="display: none;">
    <!-- Progress starts hidden, but will be shown after form submission. -->
    <div class="uploading">Uploading. Please wait...</div>
  </div>

  <div id="output">
    <!-- Blank div will be filled with "Thanks.html" after form submission. -->
  </div>


  </div>
<!--Begin Footer-->
     <div class="footer">
        <div class="bottomStrip">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-push-1">&copy; <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>, PACE, Inc. All rights Reserved.</div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-5">PACE, Inc., 739 S. Mill St., Plymouth, MI 48170-1821</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--End Footer-->
</body>
```

**Code.gs**

```
var submissionSSKey = '1e56M0GL6649pVW0SUwZDR8CjuyTqEwrkAUUWYVmiOpk';
var folderId = "0B3YZCO2xGxYFdHV4Q2pvY0U4d0U";

function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
}


function processForm(theForm) {
  var fileBlob1 = theForm.myFile1;
  var fileBlob2 = theForm.myFile2;
  var fileBlob3 = theForm.myFile3;
  var fileBlob4 = theForm.myFile4;
  var fileBlob5 = theForm.myFile5;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var doc1 = folder.createFile(fileBlob1);
  var doc2 = folder.createFile(fileBlob2);
  var doc3 = folder.createFile(fileBlob3);
  var doc4 = folder.createFile(fileBlob4);
  var doc5 = folder.createFile(fileBlob5);

  // Fill in response template
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
  var name = template.name = theForm.name;
  var email = template.email = theForm.email;
  var brand = template.brand = theForm.brand;
  var date = template.date = theForm.date;
  var amount = template.amount = theForm.amount;
  var split = template.split = theForm.split;
  var manufacturer = template.manufacturer = theForm.manufacturer;
  var pace = template.pace = theForm.pace;
  var reason = template.reason = theForm.reason;  
  var category = template.category = theForm.category;
  var subcategory = template.subcategory = theForm.subcategory;
  var message = template.message = theForm.message;   
  var fileUrl1 = template.fileUrl1 = doc1.getUrl();
  var fileUrl2 = template.fileUrl2 = doc2.getUrl();
  var fileUrl3 = template.fileUrl2 = doc3.getUrl();
  var fileUrl4 = template.fileUrl2 = doc4.getUrl();
  var fileUrl5 = template.fileUrl2 = doc5.getUrl();

  // Record submission in spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 17).setValues([[name, email,brand,date,amount,split,manufacturer,pace,reason,category,subcategory,message,fileUrl1,fileUrl2,fileUrl3,fileUrl4,fileUrl5]]);

  // Return HTML text for display in page.
  return template.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e56M0GL6649pVW0SUwZDR8CjuyTqEwrkAUUWYVmiOpk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit), in `type="button"` buttons will not submit a form and they don't do anything by default. They're generally used in conjunction with JavaScript as part of an AJAX application while `type="submit"` buttons will submit the form they are in when the user clicks on them, unless you specify otherwise with JavaScript.

I suggest to use `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"` since it will submit the form when clicked when it's inside a form element as stated in this [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).

Hope this helps!