# JQUERY Validate using different button on same form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

One is notes div 
[image: Note]

Second is Charges div 
[image: Charges]

When I click on notes submit than it's validate only notes div data like:
`txtTitle`, `txtNotes`, `txtDate`.

When I click on charges submit than it's validate only charges div data like:
`chkSetup`, `chkDev`, `chkOther`, `chkPackaging`.

My code is:

```
$('#btnNotesSubmit').click(function () {
   $('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
       txtTitle : "required,"        
       txtNotes : "required,"        
       txtDate : "required,"        
    },

    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorElement: 'span',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
           alert('notes data insert function');
      }
   });


$('#btnChargesSubmit').click(function () {
   $('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        checkbox validate data 
    },

    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorElement: 'span',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
           alert('charges data insert function');
      }
   });
```

Comment: you should also define rules for charges

Comment: how is it?
any suggestion?

Comment: Where is the HTML??

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the purpose of the `.validate()` method; there is no need to put it within a `click` handler.  The `.validate()` method is only for *initializing* the plugin on your form, and ***it can only be called once***.   Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13671820/594235).

Also, we cannot see your HTML, but your two forms (`div`'s) should be contained within **two different** `<form>` containers since they contain different input elements, different rules, and separate buttons.

Initialize them both first...

```
$('#form1').validate({  // <- initialize the plugin on FORM 1
    rules: { // rules for form 1
       txtTitle : "required,"        
       txtNotes : "required,"        
       txtDate : "required,"        
    }, 
    ....
});

$('#form2').validate({  // <- initialize the plugin on FORM 2
    rules: { // rules for form 2
        ....
    },
    ....
});
```

Then since each button is a `type="button"`, you must use a `click` handler to test each form by triggering the `.valid()` method...

```
$('#btnNotesSubmit').on('click', function () {
    $('#form1').valid();  // <- TEST FORM 1
});

$('#btnChargesSubmit').on('click', function () {
    $('#form2').valid();  // <- TEST FORM 2
});
```

However, if you simply change `type="button"` into `type="submit"`, you will not need these custom `click` handlers at all since the plugin will capture this `click` event automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$('#btnChargesSubmit').click(function () {
   $('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
       chkSetup : "required,"        
       chkDev : "required,"        
       chkPackaging: "required,"  
    },

    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorElement: 'span',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
           alert('charges data insert function');
      }
   });
```

Comment: You can also define other rules like email etc

Comment: In my page all <BUTTON TYPE="BUTTON">

Comment: I could not understand <BUTTON TYPE="BUTTON">. plz copy paste this. it will work